# Backreferences to capturing groups in re.sub not working as expected

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove any "\" followed by digits

```
s = "somecharacters\15othercharacters"
s = re.sub(r"\\(\d+)", r"\1", s)
```

`print(s)` gives me `othercharacters` while instead I expected `somecharactersothercharacters`.

Can you help me fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Your input should be `s = r"somecharacters\15othercharacters"`

Comment: The `\15` is interpreted as the escape sequence for the `\r` "Carriage Return" control character, so `somecharacters\15othercharacters` displays as "othercharacters" (try printing the original string) and doesn't contain any backslash character your regex would match

Comment: I want to get rid of the backslash followed by numbers, because they will be interpreted as backreferences.

Comment: Maybe I just replace all  backslashes.

Comment: Have you tried @anubhava's suggestion? Because the `r` prefix asks python to interpret the string as literal text, disabling the interpretation of the `\15` escape sequence. At this point you actually have a backslash followed by a number that your regex should match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this, as you requested in this part of your question:

> I want to remove any "\" followed by digits

```
import re
s = r"somecharacters\15othercharacters"
s = re.sub(r"\\\d+", '', s)
print(s)
```

When run this outputs:

```
somecharactersothercharacters
```

Comment: Yes, use raw string or re.escape(s) , and then re.sub(r"\\+(?=\d)", "", s) works.  Didn't know that \15 or some other combinations represent special characters. Thanks!